# CLI not selecteable on Windows CMD and Powershell

Tags: firebase, flutter, powershell

Please i need help, this is the second day i am battling with flutterfire configure using Powershell.

I have been able to login to firebase through Powershell terminal, now i run flutterfire configure on the terminal, it brought my demo project but i am unable to select it or create new project.

This is where I'm stuck , please help.
Thanks.